# What is the difference between { something: value } & Object.assign({}, { something: value })

Tags: javascript

I am learning react & redux. I wanted to find the difference between these two codes.

```
export default function xReducer (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // I am simply assigning my key value to the action property
        case 'SOMETHING': {
             return [ ...state, { myKey: action.x } ]
        }
        // I am using Object.assign
        case 'SOMEMORE': {
             return [ ...state, Object.assign({}, { myKey: action.x }) ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically this is just ES6, nothing to do with React or Redux really. Mosto of the times `Object.assign` is used to make a shallow copy of an object, in this case it doesn't look necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `Object.assign` in your example provides no benefit.
`Object.assign` creates a shallow copy. Basically using `Object.assign` will create a new instance of an object keeping the original object intact. In `React` terminology, it's all about keeping your object immutable.

```
var obj1 = {prop1: "A"};
var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
obj1 === obj2; //false as they are 2 different instances
```

This can be achieved doing:

```
var obj2 = {
  prop1: obj1.prop1
};
obj1 === obj2; //false as they are 2 different instances
```

Note that `Object.assign` works well for primitive types (`string`, `number`, `boolean` for the most significant ones) as they are all immutable types (cannot be changed). `Object.assign` will not create a new instance of reference types such as `Array`, `Function`, `Object`, `null`, `undefined`.

Example:

```
var obj3 = {
  fn: function() {}
};

var obj4 = Object.assign({}, obj3);
obj3.fn === obj4.fn; //true as Object.assign will not create a new instance of fn
```

When used properly, `Object.assign` is versatile and powerful.

See Mozilla's page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, in this particular example, there is no difference. You use `Object.assign` to combine multiple objects where there may be overlapping keys, such that the value of those keys in objects to the right override the value in objects to the left. The canonical example is something like this:

```
let options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, passedOptions)
```

In this case, since the only objects being merged are an empty one and a single literal one, the result is the same as the literal one by itself.